# To extract a string from among two others

Tags: python, regex

This forms part of a hobby personal project for developing a knowledge description language. 
These the text I want to extract strings:

```
begin car part chassis engine wheels begin motorbike part 

chassis engine wheels begin motorbike part wheels chassis 

engine begin tree part roots branches stem leaves begin light 

bulb part spile filament crystal begin coin part corp begin pen 

part ball pipe button begin glasses part mount 

eyeglasses begin motorbike part chassis engine wheels
```

So I expect to obtain using some kind of regex an output something like these:

['car','motorbike','motorbike','tree','ligthbulb','coin','pen','glasses','motorbike']
**Every word of the before list is obtained from the middle of two repeated words, "begin" and "part"**. It is not necessary that you have an output format like the one shown here based on a list, but I want to separate the mentioned words in some way.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: After spending 30 minutes reading SO answers and more than 1 hour looking for information related on the internet, I think the quickest option is to ask it here. I recognize that I have to learn Regex

Comment: and where does the lightbulp come from?

Comment: It could be  `begin Streetlight part lightbulp frame`

Comment: other definition could be `begin lamp part ligthtbulp frame button wire`

Comment: well but there lightbulp is not in the middle of begin and part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was the easiest solution to your problem for me.

```
re.findall(r'begin (\w+)', text)
# ['car', 'motorbike', 'motorbike', 'tree', 'light', 'coin', 'pen', 'glasses', 'motorbike']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Regex:

```
(?<=begin[\s])(.|\n|\r)*?(?=[\s]part)
```

and see it in action at https://regex101.com/r/w4xDbp/2.

### Explanation

1. `(?<=begin\s)` prepenedet by *begin* and a whitespace character (`\s`)
2. `(.|\n|\r)*?` lazy match of any characters including line terminators
3. `(?=\spart)` followed by whitespace character followed by *part*

However, it produces the output

- car
- motorbike
- motorbike
- light
  bulp
- tree
- coin
- glasses
- motorbike

please note that the newline of "light bulp" is matched too.

Comment: "lightbulb" begins at the end of the 3rd row

Comment: oh, ok, didn't see that